# swift Button display

Tags: swift, button, uibutton

I create a button from my code.

How can I write code to let button change to like Default?
Am I missing some code?
I have tried `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` or something ....

I mean when I push Button ..the button will become to transparent(I still push on) and when i push off will become back ...

like down below two images...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var testButton:UIButton = UIButton()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    testButton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
    testButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    testButton.setTitle("123", forState:.Normal)
    testButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    testButton.tag = 1
    testButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(number), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(testButton)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func number(){
    print("\("100")")
}

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could either add:

```
testButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
```

or have the colour applied in the button's function:

```
@IBAction func testButton(sender: UIButton) { 
    testButton.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

I've used redColor here for the examples, but you could change that to whatever colour you want to create the desired effect. I've not actually compiled this, so apologies if you need to correct any of the syntax to get it to work.